# Comboboxes not updating

Tags: php, mysql, list, combobox

I have two php pages, **admin_bkp.php** and **db_submit.php**.

The **admin_bkp.php** gives a user a table that let's the user set permissions to employees and save the permissions to a MySQL table called **rights**. The employee info is gathered from **hs_hr_employee** and saved to **rights tog**ether with an extra 'Permissions' column.

It was working at first, you could save the data and when you refresh the page, the **admin_bkp.php** shows you the default value in the comboboxes as you had previously chosen.

However, now it is returning the default value as **'All'** which is something I don't want. I want it to show the chosen value from before.

The **admin_php.bkp** saves the values upon clicking the **'Save'** button

This is the code:
**admin_bkp.php**

```
 <?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','root');

if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['cb_change'] ) && is_array( $_POST['cb_change'] ))
    {
        foreach( $_POST['cb_change']  as $emp_number => $permission)
        {       
echo "$permission";
            $sql = "UPDATE `rights` SET Permission='".mysql_real_escape_string($permission)."' WHERE emp_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_number)."'";
            echo __LINE__.": sql: {$sql}\n";
            mysql_query( $sql );
        }
    }
}
?>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size:36px;"><strong><span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 128);">File Database - Administration Panel</span></span></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
/*
http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/index.php?css=71

Data Tables and Cascading Style Sheets Gallery
Title: Casablanca
Author: RODrigo CASTilho Galv?o Ferreira - RODCAST
URL: http://www.rodcast.com.br
Update: 04/04/2008 10:51 AM
*/
body{
background: url('bg.gif');
}
table {
    color: #666;
    font: 0.8em/1.6em "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #fff;
}

table,caption {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 0px solid #CCC;
    border-left: 0px solid #CCC;    

}

caption,th,td {
    border-left: 0;
    padding: 10px;

}

caption,thead th,tfoot th,tfoot td {
    background-color: #216dab;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

thead th {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center
}

tbody th {
    padding: 20px 10px
}

tbody tr.odd {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    color: #666;

}

tbody a {
    padding: 1px 2px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #E63C1E;
    background: #7bafd9;
}

tbody a:active,tbody a:hover,tbody a:focus,tbody a:visited {
    color: #fff;

}

tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #333
}

tbody tr:hover a {
    /*background-color: #FFF*/
    color:fff;
}

tbody td+td+td+td a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 0;

}

tbody td+td+td+td a:active,tbody td+td+td+td a:hover,tbody td+td+td+td a:focus,tbody td+td+td+td a:visited {
    color: #fff
}

tbody td a[href="http://www.rodcast.com.br/"] {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: transparent url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAIAAACEpMf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAPAA8AAAIjjA8Qer0JmYvULUOlxXEjaEndliUeA56c97TqSD5pfJnhNxYAOw%3D%3D') no-repeat;
    text-indent: -999em;
    border-bottom: 0;

}

tbody a:visited:after {
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    content: "\00A0\221A"
}
</style>
</head>

    <form method="post" action="db_submit.php">

    <?php 


        if (!$connection)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db('users', $connection);

        #mysql_query('INSERT into rights(Emp_num, ID, Name, Surname) SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM hs_hr_employee');


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, Permissions FROM rights");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO rights (emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname)
                    SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname
                    FROM hs_hr_employee
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE employee_id = VALUES(employee_id), emp_number = VALUES(emp_number)
                    ");

        $duplicates = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, count(*) FROM rights GROUP BY emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname having count(*) > 1");

        $count = mysql_num_rows($duplicates);

        if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($duplicates)) {
        $field = $row["emp_number"];
        $limit = $row["count(*)"] - 1;
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM rights WHERE emp_number='$field' LIMIT $limit");
        }
        mysql_free_result($duplicates);
        }           


        echo "<center>";
        /*
        echo "      
        <table >
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
        <th>Change</th>
        </tr>"; */

        echo "      
        <table >
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>        
        <th>Permissions</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_number'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['employee_id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_firstname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_lastname'] . "</td>";
          #echo "<td>" . $row['Permissions'] . "</td>";



          echo "<td>
                      <select>
                         <option value='All'>All</option> 
                         <option value='Remote Gaming' selected='selected'>Remote Gaming</option> 
                         <option value='Landbased Gaming'>Landbased Gaming</option>
                         <option value='General Gaming'>General Gaming</option>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                    "; 
          echo "</tr>" ;
          echo "<input type='hidden' name='emp_id[]' value='". $row['employee_id'] ."'>";
          }


        $selected = $row['Permissions'];
            $options = array(
              "Remote Gaming",
              "Landbased Gaming",
              "General Gaming"
            );


            foreach ($options as $option){
              if($option == $selected){
                echo "<option value='$option' selected='selected'>$option</option>";
              }else{
                echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
              }
            }
          #echo "<td>" . $row['Change'] . "</td>";

          echo "</table>
                    <p style='text-align: right;'>
                        <input name='Save_Btn' type='Submit' value='Save' />
                    </p>

                </center>";

     mysql_close($connection);

    ?>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

</form>
```

**db_submit.php:**

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Data submitted successfully.</p>

<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','root');
mysql_select_db('users', $connection);

$cbchange = $_POST['cb_change'];
$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];

foreach($cbchange as $a => $b){
    echo $cbchange[$a] ." - ". $emp_id[$a];
    echo "<br/>";

    $query = "

                UPDATE `rights`
                SET `rights`.`Permissions`='".$cbchange[$a]."'
                WHERE `rights`.`employee_id`='".$emp_id[$a]."'
                ";
    mysql_query($query);
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are some images to give you a general idea of the setup.

[image]
[image]

**Original Code:**

```
   <?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','admin','root');

if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
    if( isset( $_POST['cb_change'] ) && is_array( $_POST['cb_change'] ))
    {
        foreach( $_POST['cb_change']  as $emp_number => $permission)
        {       
echo "$permission";
            $sql = "UPDATE `rights` SET Permission='".mysql_real_escape_string($permission)."' WHERE emp_number='".mysql_real_escape_string($emp_number)."'";
            echo __LINE__.": sql: {$sql}\n";
            mysql_query( $sql );
        }
    }
}
?>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="font-size:36px;"><strong><span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(0, 128, 128);">File Database - Administration Panel</span></span></strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
/*
http://icant.co.uk/csstablegallery/index.php?css=71

Data Tables and Cascading Style Sheets Gallery
Title: Casablanca
Author: RODrigo CASTilho Galv?o Ferreira - RODCAST
URL: http://www.rodcast.com.br
Update: 04/04/2008 10:51 AM
*/
body{
background: url('bg.gif');
}
table {
    color: #666;
    font: 0.8em/1.6em "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #fff;
}

table,caption {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 0px solid #CCC;
    border-left: 0px solid #CCC;    

}

caption,th,td {
    border-left: 0;
    padding: 10px;

}

caption,thead th,tfoot th,tfoot td {
    background-color: #216dab;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

thead th {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center
}

tbody th {
    padding: 20px 10px
}

tbody tr.odd {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    color: #666;

}

tbody a {
    padding: 1px 2px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #E63C1E;
    background: #7bafd9;
}

tbody a:active,tbody a:hover,tbody a:focus,tbody a:visited {
    color: #fff;

}

tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #333
}

tbody tr:hover a {
    /*background-color: #FFF*/
    color:fff;
}

tbody td+td+td+td a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 0;

}

tbody td+td+td+td a:active,tbody td+td+td+td a:hover,tbody td+td+td+td a:focus,tbody td+td+td+td a:visited {
    color: #fff
}

tbody td a[href="http://www.rodcast.com.br/"] {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: transparent url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAIAAACEpMf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAPAA8AAAIjjA8Qer0JmYvULUOlxXEjaEndliUeA56c97TqSD5pfJnhNxYAOw%3D%3D') no-repeat;
    text-indent: -999em;
    border-bottom: 0;

}

tbody a:visited:after {
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    content: "\00A0\221A"
}
</style>
</head>

    <form method="post" action="db_submit.php">

    <?php 


        if (!$connection)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db('users', $connection);

        #mysql_query('INSERT into rights(Emp_num, ID, Name, Surname) SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname FROM hs_hr_employee');


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, Permissions FROM rights");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO rights (emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname)
                    SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname
                    FROM hs_hr_employee
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE employee_id = VALUES(employee_id), emp_number = VALUES(emp_number)
                    ");

        $duplicates = mysql_query("SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, count(*) FROM rights GROUP BY emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname having count(*) > 1");

        $count = mysql_num_rows($duplicates);

        if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($duplicates)) {
        $field = $row["emp_number"];
        $limit = $row["count(*)"] - 1;
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM rights WHERE emp_number='$field' LIMIT $limit");
        }
        mysql_free_result($duplicates);
        }           


        echo "<center>";
        /*
        echo "      
        <table >
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
        <th>Change</th>
        </tr>"; */

        echo "      
        <table >
        <tr>
        <th>Employee Number</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>        
        <th>Permissions</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_number'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['employee_id'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_firstname'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['emp_lastname'] . "</td>";
          #echo "<td>" . $row['Permissions'] . "</td>";

          echo "<td> <select name='cb_change[]' SELECTED VALUE=".$row['Permissions'].">
          <option value='All'>All</option> 
          <option value='Remote Gaming'>Remote Gaming</option> 
          <option value='Landbased Gaming'>Landbased Gaming</option>
          <option value='General Gaming'>General Gaming</option>
          </select> </td>"; 
          echo "</tr>" ;
          echo "<input type='hidden' name='emp_id[]' value='". $row['employee_id'] ."'>";
          }

          #echo "<td>" . $row['Change'] . "</td>";

          echo "</table>
                    <p style='text-align: right;'>
                        <input name='Save_Btn' type='Submit' value='Save' />
                    </p>

                </center>";

     mysql_close($connection);

    ?>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">
    &nbsp;</p>

</form>
```

Can you kindly point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the correct values are displaying in the database, then your problem is with displaying the data at the other end. From what I understand, you want to output a list of permissions in an html select box, with the currently stored permission set as 'selected' for that user, correct?

If so, your code here:

```
echo "<td> <select name='cb_change[]' SELECTED VALUE=".$row['Permissions'].">
 <option value='All'>All</option> 
 <option value='Remote Gaming'>Remote Gaming</option> 
 <option value='Landbased Gaming'>Landbased Gaming</option>
 <option value='General Gaming'>General Gaming</option>
 </select></td>";
```

Is wrong. you need to match the `<option>` value to the currently selected value, then stick  attribute on it.

eg:

```
$selected = $row['Permissions'];
$options = array(
  "Remote Gaming",
  "Landbased Gaming",
  "General Gaming"
);
foreach ($options as $option){
  if($option == $selected){
    echo "<option value='$option' selected='selected'>$option</option>";
  }else{
    echo "<option value='$option'>$option</option>";
  }
}
```

That should work.

**FINAL EDIT**

The following code marked 'Code' should be placed underneath:

```
echo "      
    <table >
    <tr>
    <th>Employee Number</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>        
    <th>Permissions</th>
    </tr>";
```

Code:

```
    $options = array(
        "All",
        "Remote Gaming",
        "Landbased Gaming",
        "General Gaming"
    );

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['emp_number'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['employee_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['emp_firstname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['emp_lastname'] . "</td>";
        #echo "<td>" . $row['Permissions'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <select name='cb_change[]'>";
        foreach($options as $option){
            if($option == $row['Permissions']){
                echo "<option value='" . $option . "' selected='selected'>". $option ."</option>";
            }else{
                echo "<option value='" . $option . "'>". $option ."</option>";
            }
        }
        echo "</select> </td>";
        echo "</tr>" ;
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='emp_id[]' value='". $row['employee_id'] ."'>";
    } // end while
```

Comment: So I basically replace that piece of code with the one you've given me?

Comment: What I tried is this but it's showing multiple comboboxes, something which I don't want. What I want is a combobox displaying the previously selected option by default.I updated the code in the main question for you to see what I've done.

Comment: The code I gave you loops through each permission (as stored in the array) and outputs an <option> element for each one. You should wrap the code in a `<select>` as shown in the EDIT. I'm not sure where you got this: `SELECTED VALUE=".$selected."`. It looks like some sort of SQL query that your attempting to use in the html? As far as I'm aware that doesn't do anything in this context and is invalid.

Comment: lowe_22 I'm sorry but I'm not understanding. I updated the code again to show you what I have done.

Comment: Ok, see EDIT2 for an outline of what the code I gave you is doing. It's possible I've completely misunderstood your question and am answering something random - but have a look and see what I've done.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, but what it's doing now, is setting everything to remote gaming. Basically if I select 'Remote Gaming' for user 1 and click save, it should save that to MySQL, and when i go back to admin.php it should display 'Remote Gaming' in the combobox for user1 by default and not any other option.

Comment: I had managed to do it before and it was working fine, but for some reason it stopped working.

Comment: the query I'm using is `"INSERT INTO rights (emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname)
                    SELECT emp_number, employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname
                    FROM hs_hr_employee
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE employee_id = VALUES(employee_id), emp_number = VALUES(emp_number)`  I can't see what's going wrong, because the sql insertion was correct .. i.e. the values where being saved correctly. I updated the code for you to see.

Comment: Can you put your code back to how it was originally in your answer? I'll have a look at it and see if I can get it to work.